# $(window).load equivalent for Advanced Ajax Page Loader in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a small script to animate my content in single post when page is loaded, it's sliding from right to left side. Everything work's fine when i enter to the specific page with the post directly after entering the address... but, when i enter to this page using Advanced AJAX Page Loader http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/ then it's not working. I guess that the problem is in "$(window).load", is there any equivalent to change it ?

There is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function() {
     $('#main-content-slide').animate({'left':'0%'}, 1500);
   });
</script>
```

Sorry for my bad english i hope you understood me.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is loading via Ajax then it seems to me the content you want to animate will only load after the whole `$(window).load()` has already happened.  Window loads first, then Ajax pulls content, correct?

So you need to pay attention to where your content is and wait for that to be viewable & in-place. So maybe something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function() {
     if ($('#main-content-slide').length > 0) {
       $('#main-content-slide').animate({'left':'0%'}, 1500);
     }
   });
</script>
```

EDIT: Another idea is to place the code directly under the element that is being rendered that way it’s always assured that the '#main-content-slide' element is in place when the code runs.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the reply, but unfortunately did not work. Of course first loads window and then ajax ... It is also possible that the script is loaded for each of the first entering the page, regardless of what the tab, cuz when i refresh page with f5, it works fine...

Comment: So u meant that i have to put my script inside this ajax script before it starts? If yes, nothing is changed...:(

Comment: it look's like this http://jsfiddle.net/BNTsz/ and it's not working again, but i think that we are close